# Radio Button producing undefined value in javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, radio-button

I am trying to send the value of a radio button to a javascript function. Eventually the function will do more but my testing it has come to a dead end because I keep getting a returned value of undefined. Here is what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
 <!--
 function jobWindow(){
  var target;
  for( i = 0; i < document.jobView.sales.length; i++ ){
   if( document.jobView.sales[i].checked == true )
   target = document.jobView.sales[i].value;
   break;
  }
  alert( "val = " + target );
  //var load = window.open('target','','scrollbars=no,menubar=no,height=600,width=800,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no');  
 }
 // -->
</script>

</head>

<body>

<form name="jobView">
<input name ="sales" value="all" type="radio" />All&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input name="sales" value="darell"  type="radio" />Darell&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input name="sales" value="kevin" type="radio" />Kevin&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input name="sales" value="brad" type="radio" />Brad&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input name="sales" value="chongo" type="radio" />Chongo&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="button" value="View Records" onclick="jobWindow()"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="button" value="View Calendar" />
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `document.getElementsByTagName` like this:

```
 function jobWindow(){
  var myvalue;
  var el = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

  for( i = 0; i < el.length; i++ ){
   if (document.forms['jobView'].el[i].type === 'radio' && document.forms['jobView'].el[i].name === 'sales')
   {
     if(document.forms['jobView'].el[i].checked == true )
     {
       myvalue = document.forms['jobView'].el[i].value;
       break;
     }
   }
  }
  alert( "val = " + myvalue );
 }
```

Note also that your `break` line never executed because you were missing curly brackets:

```
if( document.jobView.sales[i].checked == true )
{
   target = document.jobView.sales[i].value;
   break;
}
```

Comment: I added the missing curly braces and it worked. Thanks for the catch

Answer (score 4):

The access path you actually want is:

```
var el = document.forms["jobView"].elements["sales"];
```

The straight dot chain (document.jobView.sales) makes an implicit call to the "all" collection, which will only work in IE. (Yes, I know that Firefox returns an identical-looking string in its error console when things go wrong, but you can't actually use it in your own code.) getELementsByTagName() and getElementsByName() will work just fine, but then you need to ensure that the elements in the returned collection are the ones you actually want. (Assume that a time will come when you want to create more than one form on the page, and that field names will collide. It will never happen, of course, unless you fail to make that assumption out of the gate, whereupon another developer will immediately add a second form to the page you just committed.)

Answer (score 3):

change **document.jobView.sales** to **`document.getElementsByName('sales')`**

Answer (score 1):

throw some debugging in there. for example put an alert() inside the for() statement to make sure it is getting a definition for `document.jobView.sales.length`.

If it doesn't make the alert, you can almost bet `document.jobView.sales.length` is undefined.

You can then do `try { var length = document.jobView.sales.length; } catch(e) { alert(e); }` to verify this.

If you verify that `document.jobView.sales.length` isn't being defined, you may have to use `document.getElementsByTagName`, and loop through them instead of `document.jobView`