# javascript: how do i push a radio value to another function?

Tags: javascript, radio-button

can't get the variable `taxRate` to be seen in the function called by the following form.  blargh!  :P

here's the HTML:

```
<form name="incomeRange" id="incomeRange" title="Taxable Income Ranges">
  <legend>Income Range:</legend>            
    <p name="incomeTable" id="incomeTable">
      please make a selexion: <br>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="B" id="B_1" value="200" onChange="var taxRate = (this.value);">200
  </label>
</p>
</form>
<form name="userAmount" id="userAmount">
  <p>Target Amount to Spend:
    <input type="text" name="userTargetAmount" id="userTargetAmount" onKeyUp="doTheMath(this.value);">
  </p>
</form>
```

and the function it calls:

```
function doTheMath(amount)
{
  var targAmt = document.getElementById("targetAmount");
  var taxAmt = document.getElementById("taxAmount");
  var totTaxEarn = document.getElementById("totalTaxedEarnings");
  var taxRt = document.getElementById("taxRate");

  console.log(amount);
  console.log(taxRate);

  if (!isNaN(amount))
  {
    targAmt.innerHTML = amount;
    totTaxEarn.innerHTML = amount / taxRate;
    taxRt.innerHTML = taxRate;
    taxAmt.innerHTML = (amount / taxRate) - amount;
  }
}
```

guess where it explodes?  taxRate is not visible from within this function.  i thought that by setting it with the onChange of the radio button, this would make it accessible... but i guess not.  how can i get that value into the variable such that i can be used in the `doTheMath();` function?

thanks for your time.  srsly.  :)

WR!

PS:  and this time, i'm unlikely to figure it out on my own... i've spent three hours on this one...  :P

Comment: BTW, i did look here: [Radio Button produced undefined...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739051/radio-button-producing-undefined-value-in-javascript-function) and tried their suggestion, but it did not work.  :(

Comment: Where are the rest of the fields?
Here is a beginning where some of the obvious issues have been looked at, but I need 3 more fields: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/mjuMA/

Comment: ...um... that's it, that's all.  :(  i'm using this placeholder as a testbed.  the actual form is populated via AJAX/PHP.  saves me the server step...  :)  which fields were you looking for?

Comment: document.getElementById("targetAmount");
document.getElementById("taxAmount");
document.getElementById("totalTaxedEarnings");
document.getElementById("taxRate");

none of which are in your posted form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in following code:

```
    <input type="radio" name="B" id="B_1" value="200" onChange="var taxRate = (this.value);">200
```

taxRate is declared with 'var' keyword makes it is visible on 'onChange' event only. Please remove 'var' keyword.

Comment: i tried that, thank you, but it did not work.  :'( within the function, `taxRate` still shows as `undefined`...  any other ideas?

Comment: Please add 'var taxRate = '';' outside doTheMath function.

Comment: just declare it in a <script> tag in HTML?  ...okay.

Comment: okay.  tried that.  now it comes up as `undefined`.  we're getting close! :)  thank you very much!

Comment: if i set taxRate = new Number; in the HTML, it evaluates to zero instead of 200...

Comment: bah.  you were right the first time.  Firefox doesn't reset the form properly on refresh.  apologies.  thank you.  would it be best to initialize this variable in the windows.onload functions?

Answer (score 0):

Skip the 'onchange' handler, and just get the currently selected value in `doTheMath`.  I would do it with jQuery this way:

```
$('radio[name=B]:checked').val()
```